# Service Called when clicking on a document in Content Navigator

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

I created a response filter to change the value of our Name property for folder to make it more readable for our users.  This all works and it displays fine.

But when the folder is opened or clicked on the name reverts back to what it was before before the response filter did any of it's work.

Is there a service called when a folder is open/when a folder is clicked on single click?

This is currently what I have as my filtered services.

public String[] getFilteredServices() {
return new String[] {"/cm/search","/cm/openFolder","/cm/lock","/cm/unlock","/cm/editAttributes","/cm/continueQuery" };
    }

Am I just missing a service here that needs put in? I can't find anything on what service would be called when clicking on an item. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is the openItem that is being called, and it is to retrieve all the attributes of the selected item.

Also, you could figure out yourself by using your browser's network-inspector and observe the request fired at the server after you click the document - really useful!